# Facebook Integration with phone gap app in android

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have created a phone gap app by following this steps as instructed on this website **http://www.andrewsavory.com/blog/2013/2517**. The is phone gap app is complete and working fine. But now I have another requirement I need facebook login and register. I am stuck at adding the facebook plugin to the existing app because I have searched on the net and found most of the project being created by CORDOVA CLI command and not what I have used while creating the project.

Any help would be appreciated

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linked tutorial is from january 2013, so it's deprecated.

For getting started with Phonegap/Cordova you should read the [CLI-Guide in the Cordova Documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface).
After you did this, you should build a new project [like i described it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25600116/phonegap-capture-plugin-with-navigator-device-undefined/25600343#25600343)

Look into the detailed Guide for the CLI, then you know, how to use it and you can build a project and add [the facebook-plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) for SingleSign-On

Comment: Thanks for voting, if you have questions to this please let me know and i'll specify my answer.